# fill NA in timeseries from same date and time, different years r

Tags: r, time-series, na

I have a time series with data from three different years. There is a lot of missing data. I would like to fill these NAs with a value from the same date and time, but a *different year*.

If, for example, there is a missing value in 2017, and data from the same date and time in 2016 and 2015, I want to average the two to fill the missing value in 2017. If there is data from only one year available, I want like to use that single data point to replace the missing value.

Here is a df with missing values:

[image]

```
structure(list(timestamp = c("2015-09-26 06:30", "2016-09-26 06:30", 
"2017-09-26 06:30", "2015-09-26 07:00", "2017-09-26 07:00", "2015-09-26 07:30", 
"2016-09-26 07:30", "2017-09-26 07:30"), ex = c(NA, 5.52, NA, 
5.99, NA, 5.56, 5.24, NA), in = c(6.08, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), nee = c(NA, -1.6965, NA, -3.4113, NA, -8.1687, -12.9374, 
NA), year = c(2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 
2017L), time = c("06:30", "06:30", "06:30", "07:00", "07:00", 
"07:30", "07:30", "07:30"), datetime = c("09-26 06:30", "09-26 06:30", 
"09-26 06:30", "09-26 07:00", "09-26 07:00", "09-26 07:30", "09-26 07:30", 
"09-26 07:30")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

And here is the ideal resulting df with NA replacement:

[image]

```
structure(list(timestamp = c("2015-09-26 06:30", "2016-09-26 06:30", 
"2017-09-26 06:30", "2015-09-26 07:00", "2017-09-26 07:00", "2015-09-26 07:30", 
"2016-09-26 07:30", "2017-09-26 07:30"), ex = c(NA, 5.52, NA, 
5.99, NA, 5.56, 5.24, NA), in = c(6.08, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), nee = c(NA, -1.6965, NA, -3.4113, NA, -8.1687, -12.9374, 
NA), year = c(2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 
2017L), time = c("06:30", "06:30", "06:30", "07:00", "07:00", 
"07:30", "07:30", "07:30"), datetime = c("09-26 06:30", "09-26 06:30", 
"09-26 06:30", "09-26 07:00", "09-26 07:00", "09-26 07:30", "09-26 07:30", 
"09-26 07:30"), ex_filled = c(5.52, 5.52, 5.52, 5.99, 5.99, 5.56, 
5.24, 5.4), in_filled = c(6.08, 6.08, 6.08, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), nee_filled = c(-1.7, -1.7, -1.7, -3.41, -3.41, -8.17, -12.94, 
-10.55)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I've tried a few solutions with for loops, and using zoo, but can't get what I need.

Comment: maybe [T H IS](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-3/topics/na.locf) function helps

Comment: Create a lookup-table with the mean values of all days in a year 1-1 to 31-12. use that as a left_join on all NA-values.